# Failure to pip install tensorflow on M1 mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

My environment is using `Python 3.7` in conda, when attempting a `pip install -r requirements.txt` I get the following.

```
Collecting tensorflow~=2.4.0
  Downloading tensorflow-2.4.4-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl (174.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 174.3 MB 20.3 MB/s 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu~=2.4.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu~=2.4.0
```

Are there any suggestions here to fix this or to get an insight into what is happening here. I believe the line causing the issue in the `requirements.txt` is

```
tensorboard~=2.4
tensorboard-plugin-wit~=1.8
```

As suggested if I try the command

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos
```

I get the following

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-macos (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-macos
```

Comment: 'python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos' => is this the pip command u ran ?

Comment: @PSR, no, I'm trying to keep as vanilla as possible. I can try the above though.

Comment: do try and let me know

Comment: @PSR I put the response in the original post.

Comment: Refer this => https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-on-the-m1-mac-410bb36b776

Comment: A caveat with the above reference, "Instead of using Anaconda, you will use MiniForge, a lightweight Python interpreter with full access to the Conda ecosystem."

Comment: Try to build the Tensorflow form source, follow the work around mentioned https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51506#issuecomment-901460541